# Hibernate does not create tables in db

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a multimodule project, where the data module is separated from the main class.

My application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

The main class is annotated with

```
@EntityScan("a.b.c.model")
@EnableJpaRepositories("a.b.c")
public class MyApplication implements ApplicationRunner
```

After starting the application database tables are not automatically created. In the previous version of the application I've used `@EnableJpaRepositories("a.b.c.model")`
but now it does not work - "Cannot resolve package model"

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by adding a dependency on the module with data package (in `pom.xml`)

Comment: To understand better your specific use case, it would be more informative, if you show your dependency for future readers.